# I can`t connecting my own library in c# project

Tags: c#

I`m trying to connect my library in project, but I get message:

"System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'LibFor2' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Lab2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Assembly a = Assembly.Load("LibFor2");
            Object fin = a.CreateInstance("Class1");
            Type t = a.GetType("Class1");

            string text = "The access modifier for a class member prevents accessing the member." +
                " For more information, see Access Modifiers.\r\n\r\nOne cause of this (not shown in the sample below) " +
                "can be omitting the /out compiler flag on the target of a friend assembly.";

            object[] par = new object[] {text};
            MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod("FindSpace");
            Console.WriteLine(mi.Invoke(fin,par));
            
            //mi = t.GetMethod("sub");
            //Console.WriteLine(mi.Invoke(fin, numbers));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're probably missing the copy on build action. Right click your file (the assembly not being found) -> Properties. Build action : Copy

Comment: See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2022

Comment: Have you referenced your `LibFor2` project in your other project, where your `Main()` method is?